# How do I install an IOS app onto someone's phone for testing without App Store?

Tags: ios, deployment

I am making an IOS app. I want somebody to test it for me. I already added their device and UDID onto my list of 100 devices that are okay to install on.

I archived a build on my computer. So now what do I do? Can I email to them and they can just download it? That doesn't seem right, but...or I do have to an outside service for them to download? I'm just confused on how to get the app file onto their phone so they can use it.

Comment: You can use diawi for that. You need to upload .ipa file and it will generate link to download your app. Here is the link:- https://www.diawi.com/

Comment: Use Testflight? You can invite external tester for test it, there's no need of UUID too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to distribute the build to users.

1. You can upload build on app store & distribute with help of **TestFlight**.
   [Check out this](https://medium.com/@dmathewwws/steps-to-put-your-app-on-testflight-and-then-the-ios-app-store-10a7996411b1)
2. [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/)
3. [App Box](https://medium.com/developerinsider/appbox-ios-apps-wireless-installation-with-dropbox-account-615274e28d2b)
4. You can use [Bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io/).

With options 2,3,4 app installation URL will be generated. User will able install build easily If their UDID is added.

Comment: is there any site which install without UDID?

Comment: apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

You can build and distribute with https://appcircle.io
Its very user friendly and free