# Install .ipa on my iOS Device without macOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xamarin.ios, expo

How can I **install an .ipa file** on my iOS device that was generated from the expo build process if I **don't own a macOS**.

I've tried dragging and dropping it into iTunes. I've also tried downloading it through the online link generated. But both fail.

Is it even possible without a macOS? And can I later deploy my app on the App Store without a macOS?

Comment: You have to distribute the achrive for AdHoc or enterprise to make that possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14021546

Comment: testflightapp.com cannot be reached. Any other way to generate a link?

Comment: Please add more info to the question. How is it build? How do you get the ipa? As you are mentioning testflight, is it distributed using testflight? If you want to upload it to Apple for using testflight or to release in app store, you can do that in your browser on the iTunes Connect website.

Comment: You might find your answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840703/how-do-i-install-an-ios-app-onto-someones-phone-for-testing-without-app-store/63840930#63840930

Comment: what is "expo build process"?